# Shutter has lost contact with ~/Pictures directory

Tags: 16.04, shutter

Shutter seems to have lost contact with my `~/Pictures` directory. Last time I used it, it displayed previous pictures. Now it displays none.

When I launch Shutter from a terminal, I get the following warnings:

```
WARNING: gnome-web-photo is missing --> screenshots of websites will be disabled!
WARNING: Image::ExifTool is missing --> writing Exif information will be disabled!
```

I tried removing and reinstalling shutter, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Shutter lost contact with the `~/Pictures` directory after I "upgraded" to Ubuntu 21.04 and persisted when I upgraded to Ubuntu 21.10. Another side effect of the "upgrade" was problems with Thunderbird losing open windows.

Solving the Thunderbird problem solved the Shutter problem. This appears to be related to the Wayland display server protocol used by Ubuntu 21.04 not working correctly.

Answer 4, to the [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1349544/alttab-stops-working-after-a-while-in-ubuntu-21-04) to the Thunderbird problem, disables Wayland, thereby allowing its predecessor Xorg to take over. This solved the Thunderbird issues, and also had the side effect of solving the Shutter problem.

In short:

- Type `sudo gedit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf`
- Find line `#WaylandEnable=false`
- Uncomment this line by removing the `#`
- Save
- Restart