# xte stopped working after upgrading to ubuntu 21.04

Tags: upgrade, shortcut-keys, xbindkeys, xte

I use xbindkeys to copy and paste using mouse 8 and mouse 9 buttons.

It worked with ubuntu 20.10 but since I upgraded to 21.04, it stopped working in some applications.

The issue seems to be coming from `xte`

If I run `sleep 4; xte 'key v'` in the terminal And

- switch to nautilus it **doesn't** print a `v`
- switch to terminal it **doesn't** print a `v`
- switch to firefox it **doesn't** print a `v`

---

- switch to chrome it **does** print a `v`
- switch to signal it **does** print a `v`
- switch to slack it **does** print a `v`
- switch to discord it **does** print a `v`

How come it stopped working in some applications but not others ?
How can I debug this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple. After installing Ubuntu 21.04, you are now on the more modern Wayland graphical system rather than the venerable Xorg server. Extremely usefull automation tools such as `xbindkeys`, `xvt`, `wmctrl`, `xdotool`, ... do not work on Wayland.

In addition, many screen recording programs do not work on Wayland, although major player OBS Studio now supports Wayland.

Why does it work on some applications? Probably because these applications run on XWayland, an Xorg emulation layer for Wayland to support applications that do not run on native Wayland.

What to do? Switch back to Xorg for the time being, or attempt to get the very young [replacing tools for Wayland](https://github.com/swaywm/sway/wiki/i3-Migration-Guide) to work.

Comment: I switched back to ubuntu Xorg on the login screen and now it works. 
awesome, thank you !

Answer (score 4):

To check whether your Ubuntu session is Xorg or Wayland:

```
$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE 
wayland
```

You can either:

1. try to replace tools relying on GUI with tools that write input events directly to `/dev/uinput`, e.g. `xdotool` with `ydotool` etc,
2. or you can switch back to Xorg.

To set Xorg as default:

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

Uncomment (remove `#`) the following line:

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

Save the file, reboot and try something like `xdotool mousemove 50 20` in terminal, it should teleport your mouse pointer near the upper left corner of the screen.