# Ubuntu 21.04 navigation stops working

Tags: mouse

My OS:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.04
Release:        21.04
Codename:       hirsute
```

I've installed it days ago on my Dell Latitude 7420, but the "navigation" of the OS stops working after like 20 minutes or so, I was not able to identify the cause of this. (Let me know if "navigation" is not the right terminology, I'm not an admin/expert)

More specifically, the navigation on the left (I've added a screenshot so that you know what I mean, though I've rotated it so that if fits the screen better) seems not to recognize that the mouse is over its icons, i.e., the mouseover effect is not shown. More importantly, though, they are not clickable anymore. The same holds for the navigation at the top (where one can shutdown the PC, for example). Also when I use <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch windows, the mouse click is not accepted/recognized anymore, I can only confirm this choice with the keyboard.

Not recognizing the mouseover is not the only issue. Sometimes (before the mouseover stops being recognized) all programs are still clickable (in the left navigation) except for thunderbird. ALso the thunderbird icon gets highlighted, but a click doesn't open the program anymore. Does this indicate that thunderbird is causing the problem? Or is it still the 'navigation' that's the issue? (Also note that thunderbird doesn't update the red dots as also mentioned below and in the other linked stackoverflow post.)

[image]

In case it's related: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> does not work to switch windows either, that's why I use <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. It's definitely not due to a misconfiguration as I double-checked the shortcuts, and it's configured correctly. So maybe that's related. In fact, this is exactly the same issue as reported [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1349544/alttab-stops-working-after-a-while-in-ubuntu-21-04), i.e., including the red dots not disappearing for thunderbird!

It's a freshly installed system, so I really don't know why this happens (e.g., whether that's a side effect from some other program like Zoom or whatever).

Help would be greatly appreciated as I use this for work, which is of course hardly possible like this. (And if you have any advise, please be detailed and specific, as I'm pretty sure that otherwise I don't know what you mean/what to do.)

Another addendum: I've also realized now that sometimes the entire OS freezes — nothing is possible anymore once that happens. I am not sure when this was caused (e.g., whether this is always the consequence of using the left navigation).

So, is there any way to:
(a) either find out what exactly is crashing (with any sort of log output), or
(b) a way to re-install those components responsible for the navigation? Maybe that resolved the problem already...

Comment: It is something you have done that has killed the dock. You imply you have installed other programs but do not say what. Re install from scratch and make clear note of what programs you are installing. It is not possible to help if you can not say exactly what you have done.

Comment: Well, it's pretty much a completely new OS, so I only installed a very few programs - those that I need to work. So you are implying that I should list all programs that I installed; would that help? I'm not really sure how helpful that really would be as I should be allowed to install these programs... Assuming that the world is deterministic I would also assume that re-installing the entire OS would not help as the same would happen again. So the primary question is how to fix that error, e.g., which components (of the OS) should be re-installed and/or how.

Comment: (FYI: added more details on thunderbird in my  question)

Comment: Do you have any Gnome extensions installed? When the system locks up, is the CPU fan spinning fast or are there any signs the system is very, very busy? 

Comment: I don't know. :) How to find out? I could post a list of all installed programs if that helps. Regarding the CPU: Na, I don't think I heard any difference. [thanks for caring/asking!]

Comment: This is a new installation of Ubuntu, but is it a new laptop?  Have you considered checking the memory chips?  Might be completely unrelated but for either a very new computer or a very old computer, I'd check the memory chips just to eliminate that as a cause.  See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591488/how-do-i-run-memtest86), for example.

Comment: Thank you, Ray, for your response!! First, it's both a brand-new laptop (<1 week! :)) and a new Ubuntu -- so all is as new as it could be. I didn't look at your example, because I'm 99% convinced that the problem is solved. I will however wait for one or at most two more days to be 100% sure about this. If there are no further crashes I will post the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved!**

As written in my question, I did not only have the problem that the navigation stops working (and sometimes also the entire OS, i.e. everything froze altogether requiring a hard reset via on/off button), but also that <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> didn't work. I was however not sure whether that was related. Now I *am* sure because after I've applied the fix to the <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> problem, no other problems occurred anymore! (For reference, the <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> problem was described and solved here [on StackOverflow](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1349544/alttab-stops-working-after-a-while-in-ubuntu-21-04))

The problem is/was that Wayland is currently buggy. Wayland is a display server protocol used by Ubuntu 21.04. Its predecessor used Xorg instead.

This is how you can confirm that Wayland is used -- and how you can change it. (My response is copied from a (seemingly unrelated) [StackOverflow entry](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352062/xte-stopped-working-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-21-04), so please like that response as well if you found my response helpful!)

1. Type `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` --> It will print Wayland (I suppose).
2. Type `sudo gedit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf` --> You will find the entry #WaylandEnable=false, from which you will have to remove the comment symbol, i.e., remove the #. I suppose that this will switch to Xorg again.

After that: no more issues with the navigation, no more crashes, and <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> works again. :)