# copy/paste between different programs stops working under Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: copy-and-paste

My OS:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.04
Release:        21.04
Codename:       hirsute
```

I've installed it days ago on my Dell Latitude 7420, and also have a bunch of other problems, reported [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1359461/ubuntu-21-04-navigation-stops-working?noredirect=1#comment2329332_1359461) -- but I hope they are not related to this one, so I don't repeat them here. Also note that the problem here (in the current post) also occurs when the other problem (in the linked post) does *not* occur, so they seem independent.

The problem: Sometimes during working, i.e., 'some time' after the reboot, copy/pasting is only possible within the same program, but not between different programs -- at least not in both directions. :)
For example: After copying a URL from firefox I can insert it again into the URL bar, but I cannot insert it into kile, another text editor, or keepass2. After the insertion command (no matter whether via CTR+V or via right-click menu, the respective goal application freezes a while, but after it reacts again, nothing happens. Strangely, I found out that copying text into certain directions is still possible. For example, copying text in keepass2 allows me to insert it into the firefox URL field -- but not the other way round.

What causes that and how can I fix this?

I wasn't sure whether the problem is related to the one described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352062/xte-stopped-working-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-21-04), so I've disabled Wayland to try out. But I don't know yet whether this helped since the problem only occurs sometimes -- and only after some while. So I have to wait and see...

Comment: It is a known bug (or feature) that when you copy something from an application and then you close that application before pasting on to another, the data copied is lost. I hope you are not talking about this "feature."

Comment: Nope, that's not it (I read about that too while searching for a solution). It's really just a bug that occurs after the OS is running for a while. If the bug doesn't occur within the next days again it will be a save bet that it was caused by Wayland as well -- since that also caused a range of other problems. I will report back in a while. :)

Answer (score 2):

I strongly assume that this problem is now solved: It didn't occur for the last two days (after I've applied the solution described below), although it occurred quite frequently before. In case there are any experts here they can probably confirm/explain (via the comments) why this solution does indeed solve the problem. I don't know why, I can just tell that now all problems (there were more, all caused by the same issue apparently) are resolved.

First, some overview: I had the following problems:

1. <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> did not work, and the red bullets next to the thunderbird icon in the navigation did not disappear, as described (and solved) [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1349544/alttab-stops-working-after-a-while-in-ubuntu-21-04/1359821#1359821)
2. The left navigation stopped working at some point and even the entire OS sometimes froze completely, as described (and solved) [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1359461/ubuntu-21-04-navigation-stops-working?noredirect=1#comment2329806_1359461)
3. And of course I had this copy/paste problem as described in this entry here.

All problems were resolved in the very same way, extracted/copied from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352062/xte-stopped-working-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-21-04). So please like that solution as well if this is helpful to you.

**Solution/problem:**

The problem is/was that Wayland is currently buggy. Wayland is a display server protocol used by Ubuntu 21.04. Its predecessor used Xorg instead.

This is how you can confirm that Wayland is used -- and how you can change it.

1. Type `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` --> It will print Wayland (I suppose).
2. Type `sudo gedit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf` --> You will find the entry #WaylandEnable=false, from which you will have to remove the comment symbol, i.e., remove the #. I suppose that this will switch to Xorg again.

Comment: Had the same problem (could not copy URL from Firefox to gedit or Vivaldi) with Wayland. Switched to Xorg. So far, seems to have helped.